# How to visualize a proper nao model in rviz?

Tags: ros, urdf, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

currently i am only seeing cyllinders in rviz being visualized as nao. How to get a proper nao model into rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132001/how-to-visualize-a-proper-nao-model-in-rviz?/) by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dnth,

There are official Aldebaran's NAO meshes available on "vrabaud' github account : the repo is named "nao_meshes"
You'll need to download an installer located in the binaries folder.

If you don't have the expected results you can follow the install section located here : "keulYSMB" github account, repository "xml_urdf_parser".

Finally if you want you can join the SIG_ROS_Aldebaran google group where you can follow/participate to the development of ros nodes for nao. There are thread about the URDF_generator.

Hope this will help.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0